# Eclipse Helios not showing Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have recently got a new computer and I have put Eclipse Helios on there. Before, on my old computer, when I used the control-assist (Ctrl + Space) and highlighted the suggested methods, the Javadoc for that method used to appear at the side of the control assist pop up window  with the method description and parameters etc...

However, on my new computer this Javadoc doesn't appear and only the method suggestions appear - but even the arguments for the methods aren't named (they're just called `arg0`, `arg1` and so on). The only thing I can think of that is different on the new install is ZoneAlarm but as far as I can see I have allowed eclipse through the firewall; unless it's something to do with Java itself.

This feature is really useful to me so any advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse is using a JRE instead of a JDK as the default Java.

- Download and install a JDK.
- In Eclipse Preferences, Java -> Installed JRE's.  Use "Add" or "Search" to locate and add the JDK just installed.
- Move the check mark indicating the default Java to the newly found JDK.
- Allow the workspace to rebuild.

Comment: You were right that Eclipse was using JRE instead of JDk! However, I have just changed that so it is uses JDK and restarted Eclipse but still nothing in the way of Javadoc. Any more ideas?

Comment: Your project(s) may have explicitly overridden the JRE used.  Check the individual projects.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply but could you please tell me how to check if one of my projects is using a different a JRE.

Comment: Project Properties dialog -> Java Build Path -> Libraries.  To change, select JRE System Library, and click Edit.

Comment: Thanks for that so much. The project was using the wrong JRE for some reason (I don't know why as I hadn't touched it) and when I told it to use the correct JDK Javadoc showed up happily! You may want to add that extra part to your initial answer so it is more complete... but thanks again.

Comment: When creating new Java projects Eclipse previously defaulted to the JRE used by Eclipse itself.  The exact version.  This gives the kind of problems you describe.  If you need to migrate to a structure not dependent on Eclipse itself, I have had good experiences with Maven.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press F3 on the Class or Method name you want to see javadoc for. Then in the editor it's source will open or if you don't have source attached, you'll have screen with bytecode saying that no sources attached. Then you need to open package view, by default it's on the left side. On the top of it there is an icon with two arrows, if it's not pressed, press it. It will show source you've opened in the package view, then you need to find `jar` file containing your source by scrolling up if you already don't stand on it.

Now press right mouse button on that jar, you'll see properties window. Select javadoc, then you need to select location of the javadoc. You can provide a URL to an online javadoc. The URL you will be pointing to must provide a page named 'index.html' or similar or Eclipse won't allow you to use that URL. Also you can download javadoc locally and then select the location of that javadoc archive. If you need the javadoc for java SE libraries, you can find it in your jdk installation directory in src.zip folder. Hope it'll help.

Comment: I don't see a dialog box saying 'javadoc not found'. Do you know where I can download the javadoc locally then?

Comment: @Andy sorry, I was mistaken. I fixed my answer.

Comment: I have done all this, and even downloaded to Javadoc to a local directory to ensure that it wasn't down to ZoneAlarm blocking any connections from eclipse (which I suspect it might be) but the Javadoc still isn't displaying. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer gasan, it went a long way to solving my problem but unfortunately Thorbjorn beat you to finding the source of the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the javadoc location of your library?

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Select your JRE -> Edit -> Select .jar file(s) (rt.jar) -> Javadoc Location

Comment: No, I haven't specified the javadoc location for the library. I am trying to do this now, but I'm not exactly sure what to do once I click "Javadoc Location"?... Could you please elaborate @Jeffrey

Comment: @Andy either provide the online URL to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) (Replacing `javase/7/` with `javase/your.version.here` depending on which version of Java you are running) or the path to a local copy you may have downloaded.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, as I said @gasan, I have now provided the  path to a location where the Javadoc should be on my computer and I have done this for every `.jar` file in the JRE but I still can't see the Javadoc...?

Comment: Thanks for help Jeffrey. I have now solved my problem thanks to Thorbjorn though...