# Find what I need the Java Documentation

Tags: java

I've looked for half an afternoon for something similar to the MSDN for Java. The closest I've found is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html. It is a very helpful place, and I've already referenced it many times.

My main is problem is trying to find things(e.g. - `arrayName.length()`) I keep trying to find that `.length()` part in the documentation. I've looked under the `Objects` class, all of the `array` classes, `attributes`(there are so many with the same name I probably skipped over a dozen without realizing it), and a few other random classes. With how I learn it makes it difficult when I can't find a simple method, albeit self explanatory, in the official documentation.

When I was learning C# all I had to do was google "keyboard event C#" and the MSDN gave me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx, then that combined with the next link down was a stackoverflow post, I had all the information I wanted, including samples, parameters, and examples.

How do I find such a simple answer in the Java documentation? I guess I'm asking how to fish, in terms of the documentation.

p.s. - This was all I could find, and it doesn't answer any of the questions I have(like 'what else can I add to the end of an array or string?').

```
getLength
public static int getLength(Object array)
                 throws IllegalArgumentException
Returns the length of the specified array object, as an int.
Parameters:
     array - the array
Returns:
     the length of the array
Throws:
     IllegalArgumentException - if the object argument is not an array
```

Comment: You're searching for a way to get the length of an array in Java? If so, you should pass an array, not an object (e.g. `String[]`).

Comment: I know how to do that. What I want to know is how do I find an answer in the official documentation, because I clearly am doing something wrong. I can't find the `.length()` part of an expression in the documentation to save my life.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html There's a header `getLength`.

Comment: Yes I agree the javadoc isn't as comprehensive as MSDN, but spend some time with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ and you should find plenty basic examples and techniques there

Comment: Search for "java array length" and you'll find the Oracle tutorial on Java arrays. You should bear in mind three major sources of documentation from Oracle: the API documentation (which you've found), the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) and the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Try to find the appropriate class first on the bottom left panel. In this case, look at String, you can find the explanation for `length` and any other method for String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set-up JDK javadoc properly in your IDE, if you are using eclipse you can follow this thread : [Eclipse Helios not showing Javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556938/eclipse-helios-not-showing-javadoc)

Go through basic java tutorial to be confident with basic Java API and for frameworks and various libraries always download javadoc with jar and search for cookbooks / tutorial e.g. 
for Apache Commons IO i found quickly : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/description.html

Comment: This helped a ton. It didn't exactly get the full scope I was hoping, but I think this is as close as I am going to get.

Answer (score 0):

In javadocs, you can find what all methods and attributes does the particular class have.
Arrays are special objects in java, they have a simple attribute named length which is final.

There is no "class definition" of an array (you can't find it in any .class file), **they're a part of the language itself.**

I would suggest you to go through the java langauage tutorials to understand these things.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/

Comment: Thank you for your input. It was going through these tutorials while I came across my question. Specifically why one page had `int max = searhMe.length();` and another page had a much longer solution with the same result. You also cleared up why it is impossible to find some things, but so easy to find others.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the object it should be attached to then it's pretty easy to find.

If you don't, there is an index at the top near the right of all methods (if you don't know what object you want).

The most common way is just to use eclipse and hit ctrl-space whenever you get stuck, that becomes second nature and is by far the most useful solution.

Had you said "arrayName.[ctrl-space]" you would have seen a list with "length" as one of the possibilities.  (also if you had said "listName.[ctrl-space]" the list would have contained size() instead of length because lists, annoyingly, don't use the same name as arrays for size, hmph.

Comment: This answered another question I had but didn't want to ask here, thank you.